# NuSMV: how to exclude a possible next state

Tags: model-checking, nusmv

I want to exclude a possible next case under specific conditions.
For example, I have:

```
token : array 1..2 of {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
next(token[1]) := case
                 x : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
                 TRUE : 0;
               esac;
next(token[2]) := case
                 x : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
                 TRUE : 0;
               esac;
-- exclude state value 1 if !position1free
...

DEFINE position1free := token[1] != 1 & token[2] != 1;
...
```

The same for all the values 1..6.
Otherwise, I have to do a lot of combinations to return only the position that are free.

Has anyone an idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is to further constraint the space of states with

```
TRANS (!position1free) -> (next(token) != 1) ;
```

Please beware that an inadvertent use of `TRANS` can result in a *Finite State Machine* which has no initial state or it contains some state `s_i` which does not have any future state:

[image]

source: [nuXmv: Introduction](http://www.patricktrentin.com/teaching/fm2018/lesson07/lesson07.pdf).

Comment: I tried that, but is not working. It runs in what you mentioned: "it contains some state s_i which does not have any future state:".
NuSMV message: No future state exists. Simulation stopped at step 2.

Comment: @P.Ana that is a consequence of over-constraining the problem, and it should be independent from the advice I gave you. Perhaps you should always include `0`as possible future value in the *assignment-style* encoding, and then require  in the *constraint-style* encoding that `0` is only ever used when `x` is false or when all `positionXfree` are false at the same time. If you want further assistance then please edit your question and include a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is working now! I missed some constraints. Because only one token is used at a time, I had to include in cases if that token is played than output all the possible states, otherwise keep its value. And in TRANS also: TRANS (!position1free & playToken = i) -> (next(token[i]) != 1); Thank you a lot!